# Remove rails authenticity token from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I pre populate the form field in the controller for @bar and when the form renders in the view, it also shows the `authenticity_token` in the view.

```
def new
  @content = params[:foo][:id]
  @foo = Foo.find(@content)
  @bar = Bar.new(title: @foo.title, body: @foo.body, foo_id: @foo.id)
end
```

Screnshot
[image]

Code for view:

```
      <%= form_for @bar do |f| %>
          <p>
            <strong>Title: </strong>
            <%= f.text_field :title, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
          </p>

          <p>
            <strong>Body: </strong>
            <%= f.text_area :body, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
          </p>

        <% end %>
```

How do I remove the authenticity_token being rendered on the view ?

Comment: This token is to prevent CSRF attack. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: Tai I don't want to remove the token itself, but the way `form_for` is renering it. This should be rendered as a HTML element, but right now it's rendering as a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your form to remove authentication token

**:authenticity_token => false**

```
<%= form_for @bar,:authenticity_token => false do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, after this, I added `authenticity_token` manually in the form. That solved the problem occuring during POST request.